# How to go about debugging big plugin-oriented Java projects e.g. ActiveMQ(non-Artemis) in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, activemq-classic

I usually got by with elaborate logging configurations. But now I want to debug parts of the ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.15.5 broker component in Eclipse (Photon). After downloading, building and running `mvn eclipse:eclipse` I now have a workspace full of component projects with no associated run configurations. For some reason `mvn install` generates an executable in `activemq-assembly/src/release/bin` but that seems to be limited and it is not obvious, what it is that I have to tell Eclipse to run.

I have had similar problems before.
In general: Do I just guess a `Main` (there are a'plenty) and search with trial-and-error? Or is there a structured approach that you can take towards debugging such loosely coupled applications?

Comment: You have to run it as _Eclipse Application_ (part of [PDE](https://www.eclipse.org/pde/)), not as _Java Application_. Also, a target platform must be specified. Alternatively, you could debug it remotely.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using remote debugging which can be used by any modern Java IDE (e.g. Eclipse, IDEA, etc.). Follow these steps:

1. Grab the ActiveMQ [source code](https://github.com/apache/activemq/releases) which corresponds to the version of the broker you're running.
2. Open the `env` file in the `bin` directory of your ActiveMQ instance and uncomment the line defining `ACTIVEMQ_DEBUG_OPTS`.
3. Set a break-point with your IDE in the ActiveMQ code.
4. Start the broker.
5. Attach the debugger.
6. Reproduce your problem and debug the code from the break-point you set.